# Symfony with web_server_bundle - How to activate the .htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, symfony

I am using [web_server bundle](https://symfony.com/doc/3.4/setup/built_in_web_server.html) to have my project in localhost without the need of WAMP.

My project is with Sf3.4.20 but I have the same issue with sf 4.2.1.

I have a `.htaccess`file in the `/web/` (or `/public/`) and the rules I wrote are not woring whereas, If I push the element to my prod server, it's working.

I am using php7.2.10 with windows.

example with a piece of my file :

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteEngine On

    # If no language subfolder, default to 'en'
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/../ [NC]
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /en$1 [R=301]
```

Comment: Perhaps an AllowOverride in apache conf si defined and set to none

Comment: I can't (or I don't know where/how) edit/create a file with virtualhost, it's working without

Comment: The internal PHP server is only for development purposes and does not understand or even read `.htaccess`, which is an Apache-only file format.

Comment: so it's not possible in this case? :(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

.htaccess files are Apache configuration files. You can't use them to configure the php built-in webserver! If you want to test your htaccess file with your application, you need to push it to a real apache!

For development, you don't need the htaccess file as routing is mostly handled by symfony itself. So if you want to run it locally (for development purposes) you should use

```
php bin/console server:run
```

(On windows, "php" is the executable .. like "C:\path\to\php.exe bin/console server:run")

Comment: I know, it's the command I use, but I want to test the .htaccess file for my prod while the website is running with it

Comment: You can't! htaccess is an apache configuration. You are using the php internal development server.

Comment: Ok too bad, I hoped :(

Comment: please mark this as the correct answer, if it was helpful! ty :)