# Reading environnement variables set from htacess inside php code

Tags: php, .htaccess, symfony

I'm currently migrating a application from a very old symfony 2.1 version into a symfony 6 version.

And there is one piece of code that doesn't work anymore I cannot understand:

inside htaccess file there is multiple definitions like this one :

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.cg\.mywebsite(\.com)?(\:[0-9]+)?$
RewriteRule (.*) $1 [E=COUNTRY:57]
```

Which says that if the host patterns follows the rewrite cond, then I can get my country value equals to 57 in my PHP code

```
$country = $request->server->get('COUNTRY', 1);
```

This works just fine in the old application, but in the new one I always get 1, as if country was not defined at all

Old application: Symfony 2.1 / Php 5

New application:  Syfony 6 / Php 8

Comment: just for kicks, can you verify that the result of  `getenv('COUNTRY`)`, or `dump($_SERVER)` and see if `COUNTRY` is there?

Comment: Depending on the structure of your `.htaccess` file the environment variable could be getting renamed to `REDIRECT_COUNTRY` before your application receives the request (and `COUNTRY` is not being re-set). You should also be setting this like `RewriteRule ^ - [E=COUNTRY:57]` - and this could even resolve the issue in some cases (because there is no _substitution_ the rewrite engine does not start over).

Comment: And it's also possible that the environment variables set by Apache are not transmitted to your CGI handler. Dumping `$_SERVER`, `$_ENV` (or having a look at `phpinfo()`) can hopefully shred light on that.

Comment: getenv('COUNTRY') results nothing, looked into $_SERVER and COUNTRY is not inside.
Also checked for REDIRECT_COUNTRY and nohthing. Changed the rewrite rule as you advised and still nothing.
Looked into $_SERVER and $_ENV and found no "COUNTRY" inside
Looked into phpinfo and i can read cgi.redirect_status_env with "no value". Could it be what you mentioned as "environement variables not transmited to cgi ?" Also note that I'm doing all this tests in local server from a windows PC

Comment: Also I don't know if this matter but the local server I'm using is the built in local symfony server.
Álvaro González how can I check if environement variables set by Apaches are transmitted or not ? 
Thanks in advance

Comment: "I'm using is the built in local symfony server" - `.htaccess` is an Apache config file. If you are using the local "built-in" web server then your `.htaccess` file is not processed (so the env var will not be set). https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53759815/symfony-with-web-server-bundle-how-to-activate-the-htaccess

Comment: I see that make sense thank you ! If you want to mention it as an answer I would accept it ! I'll setup a real test environement then :) Thanks again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> the local server I'm using is the built in local symfony server.

`.htaccess` is an Apache config file. If you are using the built-in symfony web server (or the PHP built-in web server) then this is not Apache and the `.htaccess` file is not going to be processed (and the env vars are not going to be set).

If you need the `.htaccess` file to be processed for your application logic then you'll need to run Apache, or move this logic to your application/PHP.